# using values in one table to update another

Tags: sql-server

[1]    SqlDataAdapter SDA2 = new SqlDataAdapter("
        UPDATE ACCOUNT_T 
        SET ACCOUNT_T.ACCT_BALANCE = ACCOUNT_T.ACCT_BALANCE +
            TRANSACTION_T.TRANS_AMNT 
        WHERE ACCOUNT_T.ACCT_NUMBER = TRANSACTION_T.ACCT_NUMBER", CON);

I am trying to update the ACCT_BALANCE column of the ACCOUNT_T using a the value entered in the TRANS_AMNT of the TRANSACTION_T where the ACCT_NUMBER in the ACCOUNT_T is equal to the ACCT_NUMBER in the TRANSACTION_T.

when I try to do this I get this error

> The multi-part identifier "TRANSACTION_T.ACCT_NUMBER" could not be
>   bound.

like depositing and withdrawing  in a bank application.

```
            TRANSACTION_TABLE.                        ACCOUNT_TABLE
            ACCT_NUMBER | 001    |002            ACCT_NUMBER | 001  |002
            TRANS_TYPE  | deposit|deposit        ACCT_NAME   | LAWAL|RAHMA
            TRANS_AMOUNT| 200    | 200           ACCT_BALANCE| 2000 |4000
```

I want to the account balance to increase when a deposit is made. Assume account_number 001 makes a deposit of 200, his account balance will increase to 2200.

Comment: You shouldn't use `SqlDataAdapter` for this. Use a `SqlCommand` instead. The `DataAdapter` classes are only meant for use with ADO.NET `DataTable` and `DataSet` types.

Comment: I recommend looking at SQL Server's `MERGE` command which makes doing multi-table data manipulation easier.

Comment: If you're updating from another table, you need to have a `from` part in your update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
   UPDATE AT
        SET AT.ACCT_BALANCE = AT.ACCT_BALANCE +
            TT.TRANS_AMNT 
            from ACCOUNT_T AT
        inner join  TRANSACTION_T TT on  AT.ACCT_NUMBER = TT.ACCT_NUMBER
where TT.TRANS_TYPE  = 'deposit'
```

Comment: thanks soo much, it work just once. I really appreciate.i guess my database knowledge is not good enough. anyway thanks once again

Comment: hello, please i still need help with the code above. it affects every row in the table and i want it to affect only a single row with reference to the ACCT_NUMBER

Comment: in that case throw table structure of both table and sample data.like put some data having ACCT_NUMBER and tell which row you want to update.

Comment: @LawalAbimbola ,thnks,plz put more data related with "001" in both table and clearly state what should be the balance.Also check my edited answer.

Comment: 001's account balance is meant to increase by the transaction amount added to the initial account balance. when i use the code you edited above, all the rows in the account table are affected instead of the single row which has 001 account number